# What is the prefered method to adjust network time protocol?

Tags: ntp, ubuntu-mate

When adjusting [speeding up] my boot time I discovered 2 methods to adjust NTP. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html suggested /etc/ntp.conf; http://www.pool.ntp.org suggested /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift. 
I'm curious what are the advantages and disadvantages of either method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are the same.  `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift` records the current drift adjustment.  This allows NTP to maintain the same drift setting following a reboot.  You can move this file by adding a `driftfile` to your NTP configuration file.

On kernels that support it NTP will modify the tick speed so that that the clock does not drift as much.  Various factors such as temperature can cause clocks to drift.  If the clock speed changes, the calculated drift value will change.

If you are not running the NTP daemon, you can calculate the drift and manually enter the value in the drift file.  If NTP cannot write the drift file, it may start with a setting that will cause the time to drift faster than it would normally.  NTP will eventually adjust.

Comment: Thanks, If a drift file pre-existed [populated with a single number] would it be preferable to add the servers to /etc/ntp.conf?

Comment: @pfeiffep If the drift file exists, it should contain a single number.  This would suggest that at least one server is already configured.  They can be listed by executing the command `ntpq -nc peers` while `ntpd` is running.  The default configuration should already have servers from `pool.ntp.org`.